# Java URLConnection openStream() FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, urlconnection

I'm trying to access a file through URL connection to a ftp server. The code I have used to retrieve the file and read is:

```
URL ftpurl = new URL("ftp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/home/appuser/LoginCheck/cpuLive.log");
URLConnection connection = ftpurl.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(ftpurl.openStream());
System.out.println(input);
```

But i'm getting a FileNotFound exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: home/appuser/LoginCheck/cpuLive.log
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.djblogin.codes.ProcessAll.processLogin(ProcessAll.java:413)
    at com.djblogin.codes.ProcessAll.processOperations(ProcessAll.java:39)
    at com.djblogin.codes.LoginCheck.main(LoginCheck.java:14)
```

When I give the same URL in browser i can retrieve the file. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941628/urlconnection-filenotfoundexception-for-non-standard-http-port-sources

Comment: have you tried to enter that url in the browser? what does it say?

Comment: It retrieves the file cpuLive.log

Comment: Have a look at Apache Common Net Library http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/