# Java io.FileNotFoundException; suspect port at issue

Tags: java, url, port, java-io

Context: I'm a very experienced programmer, but not a very experienced Java programmer.

I've inherited a small body of code that generates JNLP to wrap a JAR in order to gather some information about a client computer. This has always worked fine in contexts where no port was explicitly specified in a URL, but is failing in a test environment where I need to specify port explicitly.

The relevant Java code is:

```
URL RegURL = new URL(System.getProperty("jnlp.reg"));
...

try {
  //Create connection
  connection = (HttpURLConnection)RegURL.openConnection();
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  
  connection.setUseCaches(false);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setDoOutput(true);

  //Send request
  DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
  wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
  wr.flush ();
  wr.close ();

  //Get Response 
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
  ...
} catch (Exception e) {
  ...
} finally {
  ...
}
```

`RegURL` has a value of the form `"http://arthur.OURCOMPANY.com:81/fb/register.php"`, and I've confirmed that is the case. But I get a client-side error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://arthur.OURCOMPANY.com/fb/register.php
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at main.main(main.java:253)
    ...
```

This means the error is fired by the line `InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();`
I assume this means that somewhere along the way the port number got lost and it is using a URL which I would, indeed, expect to be invalid. However, I have no idea why the port number would get lost.

Any insights would be welcome.

Comment: Double check the property `jnlp.reg`, and that it still has port 81 in the url.

Comment: Wow. It's not. And it was earlier today, because I had some debugging in & checked it. Time to work out what the heck is going on here.

Comment: Ooh, I bet I've got it: calls are occurring in different contexts, and the call that asks for the JNLP to be built is coming locally, so it doesn't use an explicit port. When I component-tested earlier, I was calling the PHP that generates the JNLP directly (that is, giving an explicit browser URL). 

I'm not sure how I'm going to make this work, because the callback from Java almost certainly needs to do this with an explicit port, but that was the essence of it. If you want to, you can write something up that I can accept as an answer.

Comment: Ah. Probably something going on when we use .htaccess to map `*.jnlp` to `*.jnlp.php`. Doubtless managed to lose some context there. At least now I know what to work on!

Comment: Probably unrelated: but `urlParameters.getBytes().length)` gets the length in the default encoding, which may differ from the encoding of the message body (usually UTF-8).

Comment: Solved by a rewrite of .htaccess upstream of this so that $_SERVER[HTTP_PORT] would be preserved when building the URL to hit this particular code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2274535/882403) you might want to set `User-Agent` and `Accept` properties. My guess is that if you use non-standard port, the `URLConnection` cannot properly guess the content type you're expecting to receive.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing whatsoever to do with the port number. The URL you mention  was not found at the server. HTTP status 404. You can't get that from a a wrong port number: you would get a ConnectException.

Comment: It wasn't found because without the port number this went to a different physical server so, yes, it was related to the port number.