# reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); started to return exception

Tags: android, bufferedreader, urlconnection

This thing worked for over an year and suddenly started to return an Exception

here's some of AsynkTask :

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
try
{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    //the rest of the code doesn't go - exception works out        
}        
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Error = ex.getMessage();    
}
```

now, the url is valid - I copy it from debugger and paste in browser - it returns me a very fine json as it should.
And this whole thing worked for over an year and now it catches an Exception - FileNotFound

what it could be, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `int status = conn.getResponseCode();` to see the status.
Then try `InputStream error = conn.getErrorStream();`
These methods are from `HttpURLConnection`.

You probably get FileNotFoundException as an indication that the web server returned a 404.
This is javadoc for `public InputStream getErrorStream()`:

> Returns the error stream if the connection failed but the server sent
>   useful data nonetheless. The typical example is when an HTTP server
>   responds with a 404, which will cause a FileNotFoundException to be
>   thrown in connect, but the server sent an HTML help page with
>   suggestions as to what to do.
>
> This method will not cause a connection to be initiated. If the
>   connection was not connected, or if the server did not have an error
>   while connecting or if the server had an error but no error data was
>   sent, this method will return null. This is the default.
>
> Returns:
>       an error stream if any, null if there have been no errors, the connection is not connected or the server sent no useful data.

Also, for a case similar to yours ("I was receiving the page fine in the browser, but got a 404 when I tried to access it via the HttpURLConnection."), check this answer to see adding some request properties:
[URLConnection FileNotFoundException for non-standard HTTP port sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941628/urlconnection-filenotfoundexception-for-non-standard-http-port-sources/2274535#2274535)

Comment: the web server returned a 404 - but in browser this url shows fine

Comment: See what `getErrorStream` returns.